# Show data from datagrid in new form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagrid with data and when I call `dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick` i want to fill data from datagrif to the form. There is a code :

```
public Product something {get; set;}

private void dataGridView1_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){
int id = (int)dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value;
something = Podatci.GetproductByID(id);

FrmNewForm a = new FrmNewForm();
a.Show();
```

and logicly when i open a new form it is empty

How to access objects like textboxes from form that is open

Comment: This looks like a **DataGridView**, not a DataGrid. They're not the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass `something` to a new constructor of the form and show it there:

Add to the form:

```
public FrmNewForm(SomethingClass something) : this()
{
    txtSomething1.Text = something.Something1;
    // etc.
}
```

When you create it:

```
FrmNewForm a = new FrmNewForm(something);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// your code

FrmNewForm a = new FrmNewForm();
    //do something here the way you want to display the values
a.Show();
```

Comment: after you declare `FrmNewForm a = new FrmNewForm();` you can now access the public variables and controls on that form, when you type `a.` in you editor, the textboxes on that form will now be available in your `intellisense`.